# How to install pyclamd with pip

Tags: python, pip

pyclamd does not have a setup.py. I want to install it with pip so that I can use pip freeze to create a requirements file.

How do you install modules that have no setup.py with pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install from source control like this::

```
pip install svn+http://code.google.com/p/pyclamd/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk
```

Comment: Hmm, that one has a setup.py. I wonder why that's not the one in PyPI. Thanks

Comment: `pip install -e svn+http://pyclamd.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/` was the command I ended up using so that it would appear correctly in my requirements file.

Comment: the `-e` (editable) argument is not a must. it just tells pip to retain a checkout of the repository, instead of downloading, installing and deleting.